# Prestashop Collection Join with database

Tags: php, class, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

today I got something interesting to do and I could use some of your help.

I would like to join a PrestaShopCollection() with a table in database which I create during plugin install. To be more specific I create an override of `OrderCore` and the method `getOrderPaymentCollection()` what I try to achieve is to add one more "column" called status and what I thought I could do is following

```
public function getOrderPaymentCollection()
{
    $order_payments = new PrestaShopCollection('OrderPayment');
    $order_payments->where('order_reference', '=', $this->reference);
    $order_payments->join(_DB_PREFIX_.'payment_table ppt','ppt.id_order = ' . $this->reference);

    return $order_payments;
}
```

Is there maybe a way to achieve this? Or do I maybe have to create a collection of the payment_table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a very old question :)
join() method is buggy then you can't do this is not as join() method in DB class

Your code should be like this :

```
public function getOrderPaymentCollection() 
{ 
    $order_payments = new PrestaShopCollection('OrderPayment');
    $order_payments->join('MyModulePaymentClass');
    $order_payments->where('order_reference', '=', $this->reference); 
    return $order_payments;
}
```

MyModulePaymentClass must be declared as an ObjectModel
Don't forget PrestashopCollection code must be updated. Because an Exception is raised in each case.

Better is to use a DB::Query to do this.